# TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property find as function - NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to run my test as follow using the TDD aproach. I have the same test running on another app (I copy paste it) and it works but in this test I get the following error:

> TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property find as function
>   Model file

/*
 Task Model Database models
*/

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    try {
      module.exports = mongoose.model('Task');
    } catch (error) {
      const taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        title: { type: String, required: true },
        status: { type: Boolean, required: true }
      });
      module.exports = taskSchema;
    }
```

/* Sample Test */

```
'use strict';

const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const expect = chai.expect;
const Task = require('../../models/task');
chai.should();
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

//TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT
describe('Todo Controller', () => {
  const expectedResult = { status: 201, tasks: [{}], message: '' };

  //Testing if the array has a valid status
  it('should get a valid status', done => {
    const TodoMock = sinon.mock(Task);

    TodoMock.expects('find').yields(null, expectedResult);
    Task.find((err, result) => {
      TodoMock.verify();
      TodoMock.restore();
      expect(result.status).to.be.equal(201);
      done();
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Mention your '../../models/task' file to get better idea.

Comment: @Dipten done sir

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some scoping issues. I would write the model like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const taskSchema;

try {
  taskSchema = mongoose.model('Task');
} catch (error) {
  taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    status: { type: Boolean, required: true }
  });
}

module.exports = taskSchema;
```